# Getting the average of a certain hour on weekdays over several years in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, average, statistics

I have an hourly dataframe in the following format over several years:

```
Date/Time            Value
01.03.2010 00:00:00  60
01.03.2010 01:00:00  50
01.03.2010 02:00:00  52
01.03.2010 03:00:00  49
.
.
.
31.12.2013 23:00:00  77
```

I would like to average the data so I can get the average of hour 0, hour 1... hour 23 of each of the years.

So the output should look somehow like this:

```
Year Hour           Avg
2010 00              63
2010 01              55
2010 02              50
.
.
.
2013 22              71
2013 23              80
```

*Does anyone know how to obtain this in pandas?*

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Note: Now that Series have the dt accessor it's less important that date is the index, though Date/Time still needs to be a datetime64.*

Update: You can do the groupby more directly (without the lambda):

```
In [21]: df.groupby([df["Date/Time"].dt.year, df["Date/Time"].dt.hour]).mean()
Out[21]:
                     Value
Date/Time Date/Time
2010      0             60
          1             50
          2             52
          3             49

In [22]: res = df.groupby([df["Date/Time"].dt.year, df["Date/Time"].dt.hour]).mean()

In [23]: res.index.names = ["year", "hour"]

In [24]: res
Out[24]:
           Value
year hour
2010 0        60
     1        50
     2        52
     3        49
```

If it's a datetime64 *index* you can do:

```
In [31]: df1.groupby([df1.index.year, df1.index.hour]).mean()
Out[31]:
        Value
2010 0     60
     1     50
     2     52
     3     49
```

---

Old answer (will be slower):

Assuming Date/Time was the index* you can use a mapping function in the [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
In [11]: year_hour_means = df1.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.hour)).mean()

In [12]: year_hour_means
Out[12]:
           Value
(2010, 0)     60
(2010, 1)     50
(2010, 2)     52
(2010, 3)     49
```

For a more useful index, you could then create a MultiIndex from the tuples:

```
In [13]: year_hour_means.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(year_hour_means.index,
                                                           names=['year', 'hour'])

In [14]: year_hour_means
Out[14]:
           Value
year hour
2010 0        60
     1        50
     2        52
     3        49
```

* if not, then first use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('Date/Time')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had been trying with loops but this is a much better way.

Comment: P.S.: Does anybody how you can fill the "x.year" or "x.hour" of "df1.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.hour)).mean()
" as a dynamic parameter into the lamda function? Defining Varialbe1=x.year and Variable2=x.hour for this "df1.groupby(lambda x: (Variable1, Variable2)).mean()
" does not seem to work.

Comment: @MarkusW You should ask that as a new question :)... it sounds like you want to use a proper function (i.e. not a lambda)

Comment: @AndyHayden you are a genius. Could you clarify something: does a lambda function always default to using the index? Then given a multiindex, this defaults to a tuple of that multiple index?

Comment: @josh yes, though you can pass `as_index=False` to override that. In re-reading this question I would do something different. Updated with a much better way to do this (which happens to create the multiindex directly).

Comment: how would I groupy by 10 mins given I have datetimeindex that in 10min interval over multiple days

Answer (score 2):

If your date/time column were in the datetime format (see dateutil.parser for automatic parsing options), you can use pandas resample as below:

```
year_hour_means = df.resample('H',how = 'mean')
```

which will keep your data in the datetime format. This may help you with whatever you are going to be doing with your data down the line.

Comment: This doesn't average from one day to the next though

Comment: @endolith  Try daily_average = df.resample('D').mean()   where df has datetimeindex