# Get the average year (mean of days over multiple years) in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas, time-series

I am new to Pandas timeseries and dataframes and struggle getting this simple task done.
I have a dataset "data" (1-dimensional float32-Numpy array) for each day from 1/1/2004 - 12/31/2008. The dates are stored as a list of datetime objects "dates".
Basically, I would like to calculate a complete "standard year" - the average value of each day of all years (1-365).
I started from this similar (?) question ([Getting the average of a certain hour on weekdays over several years in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967165/getting-the-average-of-a-certain-hour-on-weekdays-over-several-years-in-a-pandas)), but could not get to the desired result - a time series of 365 "average" days, e.g. the average of all four 1st of January's, 2nd of January's ...

A small example script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

startdate = datetime.datetime(2004, 1, 1)
enddate = datetime.datetime(2008, 1, 1)
days = (enddate + datetime.timedelta(days=1) - startdate).days
data = np.random.random(days)
dates = [startdate + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, days)]

ts = pd.Series(data, dates)
test = ts.groupby(lambda x: (x.year, x.day)).mean()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Group by the *month* and day, rather than the year and day:

```
test = ts.groupby([ts.index.month, ts.index.day]).mean()
```

yields

```
1  1     0.499264
   2     0.449357
   3     0.498883
...
12  17    0.408180
    18    0.317682
    19    0.467238
...    
    29    0.413721
    30    0.399180
    31    0.828423
Length: 366, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, searched quite a while for this :)