# Merging two dataframe by date

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe

I have two dataframe, using pandas, one (df_1) is the average temperature by day of the year until some point in time (for example the average temperature for all the days of 2014 until 03/01/2014) and the other (df_2) is the average temperature by day for the last 30 years.

What I want to do is to complete the first dataframe by the mean values by day in the second, I can't use the day of the year because of some leap years but I'm not sure this the right way. I have found a way to get the average temperature by day ([Get the average year (mean of days over multiple years) in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304881/get-the-average-year-mean-of-days-over-multiple-years-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1)) to get df_3. My end goal is to complete df_1 for the missing days (so 04/01/2014,...,31/12/2014)

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
               'Date': ['01/01/2014','02/01/2014','03/01/2014'], 'T_Avg_2014': [5,6,0.7]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
               'Date': ['01/01/2009','02/01/2010','01/01/2011'], 'T_Avg': [5,-8,-7]})




index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('1', '1'),
                                   ('1', '2'),
                                  ('1', '3'),
                                   ('2', '1')],
                                 names=['month', 'day'])
columns = [('T_Avg')]
df_3 = pd.DataFrame([3,4,8,10],
                 index=index,
                 columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to accomplish this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create date ranges
date1 = pd.date_range(datetime(2014,1,1), datetime(2014,3,1)) # 2014
date2 = pd.date_range(datetime(1983,1,1), datetime(2013,12,31)) # 30 years

# Create data frames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'temperature': np.random.rand(len(date1))*100}, index = date1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'temperature': np.random.rand(len(date2))*100}, index = date2)

# Compute average daily temperature from 30 year data
df3 = df2.groupby([df2.index.month, df2.index.day]).mean()
df3 = df3.reset_index().rename(columns={'level_0': 'month', 'level_1': 'day'})

# Get data to use to complete df1
idx = df3.index[(df3.month == 3) & (df3.day == 1)][0] + 1 # All past March 1st
data_fill = df3.loc[idx:, ['month', 'day', 'temperature']]
data_fill['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(data_fill.month.map(str)+'-'+data_fill.day.map(str)+'-2014')
data_fill = data_fill.set_index('date_time')
data_fill = data_fill.drop(columns=['month', 'day'])

# Combine data frames
df4 = pd.concat([df1, data_fill])

# Visualize data
df4.plot()
```

[image: Combined temperature data]

Notice how the data after March 1st is smoothed, because it is a 30 year average of the randomly generated data, while the data for the first 2 months has not been averaged.